# Relationship between java memory allocation needs and available memory/swap

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, swap

when starting a new java process we are getting an error which sounds like this:

```
"Could not reserve enough space for 16775168KB object heap"
```

Looking at the log file produced by JVM we see however the following:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 32744 bytes for ChunkPool::allocate
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
```

At the same time at the bottom of the log file there is a statement:

```
Memory: 4k page, physical 67098420k(52119824k free), swap 86034256k(8132400k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_45-b15), built on Apr 30 2015 12:40:44 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)
```

How can the java process fail to allocate 1GB of memory if at the same time there is a bigger amount of memory available for both the physical memory and the swap space?

Thanks a lot

Boris

Excerpt from the log file:

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 32744 bytes for ChunkPool::allocate
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (allocation.cpp:273), pid=17164, tid=21188
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b15) (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. 
#

...

VM Arguments:
java_command: com.uniper.rest.bridge.ExternalBridge -Xmx128m
java_class_path (initial): D:\Progs\ENDUR-~1\EN57BD~1\bin\otk\openjvs...
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=D:\Progs\Endur-64bit\Endur_V15_0_05052016EON_07072016_1104\bin\olf_dependencies\java\jdk1.8.0_45\
...


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.23807)

CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 26 stepping 5, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 67098420k(52119824k free), swap 86034256k(8132400k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_45-b15), built on Apr 30 2015 12:40:44 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)
```

Comment: What command line arguments are you using? Note also that the error message says it's trying to allocate 16 gig, not 1 gig. 16,775,168KB. This absolutely will fail if you're in 32-bit mode.

Comment: I am not specifying any command line arguments - so the default values are used. We also tried to specify -Xmx (e.g. -Xmx128M or even -Xmx10G) argument but we did not see any change/effect. This is executed on a 64 bit host which has about 64GB RAM.

Comment: The issue seems to be fixed by using java.exe instead of javaw.exe. But it is not clear why.